# Is there an alternative to "Everything" on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, spotlight

**Spotlight** does pretty much, but it lacks two critical features.

1. It cannot search arbitrary locations. It excludes system locations for a better user experience I guess.
2. It cannot index external drives.

For example I often search the ID of a chrome extension to get to its folder. That's way faster than typing the path. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this on OS X

Is there an alternative on OS X that includes the features of **Everything**?

Comment: So far - my spotlight can index external Devices and also System Folders ... Please check your Settings and let us know

Comment: Try to use [Alfred][1].  It is free without PowerPack.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858678/sql-server-2008-login-failed-the-login-is-from-an-untrusted-domain-and-cannot

Comment: @bMalum, the system only offers one simple page for the settings. I have checked all the items, and have no folders excluded.

Comment: @bMalum, my external devices are formatted as NTFS. I don't know if this matters.

Comment: @demas, thanks. But this seems to link to a question concerning SQL.

Comment: @Aszune'sHeart, Sorry. it was my mistake.  Here is correct link - http://www.alfredapp.com

Comment: Searching for something or for specific. Do you always know the file name you are searching for?

Comment: @Buscar웃, it cannot not be more specific. For example I often search the ID of a chrome extension to get to its folder. That's way faster than typing the path. Unfortunately, I cannot do this on OS X.

Comment: Why is this question down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case probably the

> mdfind

will do great job.

It is not a GUI but a [Terminal command](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/03/digging-deeper-mastering-spotlight-in-os-x/), and it will search everywhere and everything.

Once found you can triple click on the line (to select it) and Right Click and use the "Reveal in Finder".

Answer (score 0):

If you show hidden files you might be able to search for them via spotlight. Most drives should be indexed (as long as their HFS+ formatted I believe)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find some way to reconfigure Spotlight or some third party tool (that's Spotlight-quick or Everything-quick) to find hidden files, like those in ~/.ssh, for some time now.  The only thing I've found that works so far is [GoToFile](https://www.soma-zone.com/GoToFile/), if you remove the exclusions from the scan parameters.